# Can't login with custom authentication backend

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I creating custom authentication backend using LDAP. I want to check is user exist in database, but "delegate" password check to LDAP (password changes often due to company policy).

Backend work well when using django admin interface, but when I creating custom login page with FormView i getting following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 1.7
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'defekts',
 'account')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/var/www/django_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/django_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/django_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/django_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  173.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/var/www/django_local/local/account/views.py" in form_valid
  17.         auth_login(form.request, user)
File "/var/www/django_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  86.     if SESSION_KEY in request.session:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'account.LDAPBackend.LDAPBackend',
)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin, messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout
from django.views.generic import FormView

# Create your views here.

class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'account/login.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("defekts:index")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.get_user()
        auth_login(form.request, user)
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

account/LDAPBackend/**init**.py

```
import ldap
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, check_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class LDAPBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):

        if username is None:
            return None

        try:
            # user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            # TODO: Raise error
            return None

        try:
            connection = ldap.initialize("ldap://example.com")
            connection.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
            connection.simple_bind_s("example.com\\"+username, password)
        except ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
            return None
        except ldap.SERVER_DOWN:
            # TODO: Return error instead of none
            return None

        return user

    def get_user(self, userid):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=userid)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ametaireau/django-auth-ldap or at lease take a look on implementation

Comment: I am using python 3.4 for this project, tried fork of this project - but they doesn't work well, so I decided to create own simple backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `auth_login`, do `self.request` and not `form.request`.

Comment: No worries, it happens. Technically they (Django) shouldn't have had `request` attribute on the form and not fill it.

Comment: I am new in django and python, so i bit confused. I don't see any reason in adding request to form. Can you please explain?